# Should an apostrophe be used when writing "predeceased by her husband's"?

Tags: punctuation

Should there be an apostrophe after husband when writing "she is predeceased by her husband's" or should it be husbands?

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe is used to indicate the possessive, not the plural.  Therefore:

- If she is predeceased by a single husband, then just "by her husband".
- If she is predeceased by more than one husband, then definitely "by her husbands" (with **no apostrophe**).
- If she is predeceased by something that belongs to her husband, then you can say "her husband's (dog/cat/elephant/turtle/whatever)."

Comment: She was predeceased by her husband and by her husband's two sons.

Comment: ...and by her husband's two sons' dogs as well.